# Amazon Alexa Intent Skill Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Hey Is it just me or is Amazon having problems on their server?

I'm on the page where we set up our json intents and sample utterances

But when I try to save it. It's just loading and loading. I tested this out on another laptop and it's just loading as well

Am I the only one with this problem? Can someone try saving their intents on the developer console and get back to me?

You can see that the interaction Model just constantly loading

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens occasionally. Usually it sorts itself out after a few hours. Sometimes longer on a weekend. You can post a notice in their forums and they'll say "gosh I'm sorry" and usually get back to you when it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem using Edge but Chrome worked.